# MyBatis query parameters for Filtering

Tags: java, mybatis

I am having trouble setting query parameters with MyBatis 3. I am using a Select Provider.
Here is the method in my Mapper interface:

```
@SelectProvider(type=my.package.VolunteerSQL.class, method="getQuery")
public List<VolunteerRecord> getOrderedVolunteerList(
        @Param("from") int from, 
        @Param("count") int count, 
        @Param("orderBy") String[] orderBy,
        @Param("filterBy") String[] filterBy,
        @Param("filterValue") String filterValue);
```

Here is the Select Provider method:

```
public String getQuery(Map<?,?> parameters) {
    final String[] orderBy = (String[]) parameters.get("orderBy");
    final String[] filterBy = (String[]) parameters.get("filterBy");
    String sql = new SQL() {{
        SELECT("v.id as id, surname, forename, more columns...");
        //SELECT("more columns...");
        FROM("volunteer v");
        if (filterBy!=null) {
            for (int i=0; i<filterBy.length; i++) {
                String filter = filterBy[i];
                if (i>0) OR();
                WHERE(filter+" LIKE '%#{filterValue}%'");
            }
        }
        GROUP_BY("vs.volunteer_id");
        for (String order : orderBy) {
            ORDER_BY(order);
        }
    }}.toString();
    String result =  sql+" LIMIT #{from},#{count}";
    System.out.println("SQL="+result);
    return result;
}
```

There are a couple of problems here.
Firstly, if I have any filters, I get this exception:

```
Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
```

It seems the generated SQL does not have enough parameter placeholders for my parameters, but when I inspect the SQL it looks OK. Not sure what's going on there.

Secondly, the filter columns are open to SQL injection attack because I cannot use parameters for them, I must concatenate them directly into the SQL string. Is there a nice, clean alternative which is secure?

Comment: Another approach is to use XML as mappers. It gives a little more work but it became more readable.

Comment: @NickJ I also strong recommend you to refactor into XML which is much more easier